# Replace Text Smiley to image format

Tags: php, arrays

After searching through post on google and on this site i found this following code usefull for me , but seems its not working as i wanted .

I want to replace this " :) " to a gif image of a happy smiley , though my page only shows " :) " instead of a gif image ..

I known its very easy but the problem is im new to this . Any help would make me develop myself.  Explaining the answer in code will help me learn fast . Thanks very much.

```
 <?php 
 $string = Some text which inlcudes smiley like :);
 $emoticons = array( '<img src="images/smile.gif">' => array(':-)', ':)' , ':o)'),
 '<img src="images/sad.gif">'   => array(':-(', ':(', ':-|'));
 foreach ($emoticons as $emotion => $icons)
    {
        $string = str_replace($icons, " $emotion ", $string);
      }
 echo $string;
 ?>
```

Comment: You code works fine.. Check if the image is properly getting retrieved from your directory or if the image really exists or not.

Comment: directory and image path are proper , dont known why this is happening :( ,, though any other solution ? :)

Comment: I checked your code.. It's working pretty perfect. Try moving the `sad.gif` and `smile.gif` to the directly where you are running this code and remove the `image/` from your array and do a try.